# Using variables in a file path directory in a batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file, path, directory, cmd

I have a reasonably simple question, however i cannot seem to find a solution anywhere.

I'm working with some variables in a batch file, and i would like to change the directory according to the variable.

eg,

```
variable SET /Jan2000 = a
cd P:\Reference\Data\2000\%a%
```

When i run the batch file, it just stays in the "2000" folder, it does not go the folder below like i ask. Is there any way to get this to work?

Edit: by request, here is the exact code as it is writtenin the batch file. Thanks for the help.

```
chdir /D P:\Reference\Data\2000
SET Jan2000 = a
chdir P:\Reference\2000\%a%   
dir
pause
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to `SET` your variable.

For example:

```
SET a=Jan2000
CD P:\Reference\Data\2000\%a%
```

Comment: Apologies, i had already SET it, i just forgot to type it in my question.

Comment: Look at your `SET` command. You are creating a variable named `Jan2000` and giving it a value of `a`. Then, in the next line you are trying to access a variable named `a`. Also, leave out the spaces around the equal...`SET a=Jan2000`.

Comment: Im really sorry if this sounds stupid, but im not sure what you mean. The folder below is called "jan2000", which is now assigned to 'a', so why wont it move down to the new folder?

Comment: Your `SET` command is backwards. The variable name goes on the left side of the `=` and the value goes on the right side. Look at the difference between your code and mine.

Answer (score 5):

I can't add much to @aphoria's answer but try this

```
set a=jan2000
pushd P:\Reference\Data\2000\%a%
```

Using `pushd` instead of `cd` incase there's a problem with changing directory over drives. (I know, the `/d` switch is for that, but worth a shot).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree.  I need to keep a rotating week's worth of daily backups, so I create a day-of-the-week folder by extracting the 3-letter weekday from the system date:

```
set Today=%DATE:~0,3%
Echo  The day of the week is %Today%
If exist U:\%Today% rd U:\%Today% /s /q
md U:\%Today%
```

followed by various Robocopy commands writing to the U:\%Today% folder